# How to programmatically log user in with Spring Security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

What's the proper way to programmatically log a web visitor in under a particular username in Spring and Spring Security 3.1?  It seems the way I was doing it under 2.5 has changed a little.  I'm sure there's a much better way of doing this now.

Basically, when I create a new user, I need to also log them in at the same time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create an `Authentication` (usually a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`) and then call

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)
```

Comment: and set the password of a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken to an empty string?  Seems so in-elegant for something I have to imagine is so commonly needed.  What webapp nowadays doesn't auto-log you in when signing up?  At least with limited permissions...

Comment: Then implement your own Authentication, or subclass AbstractAuthenticationToken.

Comment: curious why there isn't already a simple, even declarative, way to programmatically log people in?  At least a password-less AuthenticationToken..

Comment: You don't have to use an empty string, you can use the password they registered with.

Comment: I guess for the specific situation of a new user registration that makes sense, but otherwise like most websites I don't store plaintext passwords and even if I did it's an unnecessary lookup.

Comment: I have tried this, however my custom user getter methods are available within principal, wheras they when logged in normally ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/7900994/106261

Comment: @at. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken doesnt require password in plain text. It uses hashed password so you can just take it from database for any user. You can delete your comments because they can mislead people

Answer (score 4):

This three lines of code do the work for me:

```
        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, password );
    Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate( request );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( result );
```

Comment: I am looking a way to add the remember-me functionality in the same elegant way....

Comment: Did you find a solution for remember-me?

Comment: This might have the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806921/log-user-in-with-remember-me-functionality-in-spring-3-1

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in doing this for testing purposes you can do this:

```
    UserDetails user = _userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    TestingAuthenticationToken token = new TestingAuthenticationToken(user,null);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
```

Where user service is your thing that implements UserDetailsService

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that extends Spring's `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`.

Here is the code:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authResult;
        WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) token.getDetails();
        String address = details.getRemoteAddress();
        User user = (User) authResult.getPrincipal();
        String userName = user.getUsername();
        System.out.println("Successful login from remote address: " + address + " by username: "+ userName);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) failed.getAuthentication();
        WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) token.getDetails();
        String address = details.getRemoteAddress();
        System.out.println("Failed login try from remote address: " + address);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how this solves the problem of auto-logging in someone upon signup.

Comment: Is this what you looking for: forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?28165-Automatic-login-after-user-registration

Comment: I didn't know the authorities will automatically be looked up with `authenticationManager.authenticate(token)`.  Thanks.