# Log user in with remember-me functionality in Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, security, remember-me

I currently log users in programmatically (like when they login through Facebook or other means than using my login form) with:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities)
);
```

What I want to do instead is log the user in as if they set the remember-me option on in the login form.  So I'm guessing I need to use the `RememberMeAuthenticationToken` instead of the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?  But what do I put for the `key` argument of the constructor?

```
RememberMeAuthenticationToken(String key, Object principal, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
```

***UPDATE***: I'm using the [Persistent Token Approach described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/remember-me.html).  So there is no key like in the Simple Hash-Based Token Approach.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to set the Authentication in the SecurityContextHolder?   Or do you need set the remember-me cookie too?

Comment: I want to log the person in and my app remembers them so they don't have to login again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume you already have `<remember-me>` set in your configuration.

The way remember-me works is it sets a cookie that is recognized when the user comes back to the site after their session has expired.

You'll have to subclass the `RememberMeServices` (`TokenBased` or `PersistentTokenBased`) you are using and make the onLoginSuccess() public.   For example:

```
public class MyTokenBasedRememberMeServices extends PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices {
    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication successfulAuthentication) {
        super.onLoginSuccess(request, response, successfulAuthentication);
    }   
} 

<remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices"/>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="foo.MyTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
    <!-- etc -->
</bean>
```

Inject your RememberMeServices into the bean where you are doing the programmatic login.   Then call `onLoginSuccess()` on it, using the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken that you created.   That will set the cookie.

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = 
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
getRememberMeServices().onLoginSuccess(request, response, auth);
```

**UPDATE**

@at improved upon this, with no subclassing of `RememberMeServices:`

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = 
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

// This wrapper is important, it causes the RememberMeService to see
// "true" for the "_spring_security_remember_me" parameter.
HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    @Override public String getParameter(String name) { return "true"; }            
};

getRememberMeServices().loginSuccess(wrapper, response, auth);
```

Comment: In my security XML configuration, I simply have `<remember-me token-validity-seconds="31536000" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>` within the `<http>` element.  Where is the `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` bean defined?  Using this mechanism, do I not need to mess with the SecurityContextHolder anymore?  Sounds like a much better solution in general to programmatically logging someone in.

Comment: I assume that I need the `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` instead of `TokenBasedRememberMeServices`.  But either way and if I can inject it into the controller where I'm trying to log someone in with remember-me functionality, `loginSuccess()` doesn't seem what I want.  Javadocs say, "Examines the incoming request and checks for the presence of the configured "remember me" parameter. If it's present, or if alwaysRemember is set to true, calls onLoginSucces."

Comment: Which version of Spring Security are you using?  I was referring to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices for 3.0.

Comment: I mentioned in the title of my question, 3.1.  I think it's the same `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` for hash-based tokens.  But As I mentioned in my question, I'm using the Persistent token-based approach.

Comment: Sorry, I meant onLoginSuccess(), not loginSuccess().

Comment: You can do that for either the Persistent or regular versions of the `TokenBasedRememberMeServices`.   I just checked the 3.1 source (sorry, I missed that) and it is the same.

Comment: `onLoginSuccess()` is a protected method.  And it takes an `Authentication` object, do I just pass a `RememberMeAuthenticationToken`?  Then I'm right back to where I started...

Comment: Pass the Authentication object that you created in your controller.  Subclass `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` and make `onLoginSuccess()` public.

Comment: What authentication object I created in the controller?  How do I create this?  That's my whole original question!

Comment: The UsernamePasswordAuthentiationToken.

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
  new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities)
);

Comment: Got everything to work, but by using loginSuccess instead and passing an overridden HttpServletRequestWrapper which returns "true" for getParameter("_spring_security_remember_me").  Spring Security certainly doesn't make this seemingly very common functionality intuitive.

Comment: How do you get a handle on the HTTPServletRequest and response? Is this code part of the FilterChain?

Comment: Yes, they are parameters to the `doFilter` method.

Comment: Thanks! I am doing the setAuthentication as part of a POJO class, where I do not have a handle on the HTTPServletRequest and Response. How do I deal with this issue? I have asked this question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041685/set-spring-security-remember-me-cookie-after-login-via-facebook

Comment: What class/method are you in when you need to access the request/response?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320674/spring-how-do-i-inject-an-httpservletrequest-into-a-request-scoped-bean

Comment: The control is in the class that gets called-back once Facebook.com finishes auth and returns the access_token. At this point, I create the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and set auth. But don't know how to do the last step getRememberMeServices().loginSuccess(wrapper, response, auth);

Comment: I can get the request, but not the ServletResponse.

Comment: No need to extend class or use wrapper. Just set alwaysRemember=true on PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices. Unfortunately it seems that it can't be done via <remember-me> XML element, so you would need to define bean PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices and set that property to true. After that normal rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(req, res, auth) creates cookie and persistent record

Comment: Спасибо, 2 дня пытался натсроить remember-me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the source for the constructor.

```
public RememberMeAuthenticationToken(String key, Object principal, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(authorities);

    if ((key == null) || ("".equals(key)) || (principal == null) || "".equals(principal)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor");
    }

    this.keyHash = key.hashCode();
    this.principal = principal;
    setAuthenticated(true);
}
```

The key is hashed and its used to determine whether the authentication used for this user in the security context is not a 'forged' one.

Have a look at the `RememberMeAuthenicationProvider` source.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (!supports(authentication.getClass())) {
        return null;
    }

    if (this.key.hashCode() != ((RememberMeAuthenticationToken) authentication).getKeyHash()) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage("RememberMeAuthenticationProvider.incorrectKey",
                "The presented RememberMeAuthenticationToken does not contain the expected key"));
    }

    return authentication;
}
```

So to answer your question, **you need to pass the hash code of the `key` field of the `Authentication` representing the user**.

Comment: I still have no idea what to do..  how do I get the `Authentication` representing the user.  And then what exactly do I pass as the key argument?