# Progammatic remember-me with spring secruity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, remember-me

My remember-me bean definition looks like this, and works fine

```
<security:remember-me  data-source-ref="dataSource" user-service-ref="userService"/>
```

However the first time a user registers, and I want to programmatically log them in and perform a remember-me. I do not know how to access the remember-me service. I can do this

```
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = 
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, "", authorities);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    @Override public String getParameter(String name) { return "true"; }            
};
```

But how to access the remember-me service like below, as I am using the default spring implementation and not my own bean ?

```
getRememberMeServices().loginSuccess(wrapper, response, auth);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811334/106261)

**EDIT**
I have changed my bean definition to look like this

```
<security:remember-me services-alias="rememberMeService" data-source-ref="dataSource" user-service-ref="userService"/>
```

But intellij is still coming back with an error when I try to inject like this :

```
@Resource(name = "rememberMeService")
private RememberMeServices rememberMeService;
```

Comment: Try replace your _@Resource_ by _@Inject_ or _@Autowired_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `services-alias` attribute of the [`remember-me` namespace element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-remember-me) to set a bean alias for the `RememberMeServices`. You can then inject that reference into other beans you create yourself.

Comment: ok thanks, I tried that but still getting an error - see my edit ?

Comment: for anyone else out there, intellij inspection incorrectly highlights this as an error : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101018