# Set spring security remember me cookie after login via facebook

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am building a mobile web app that has the option to login via facebook/twitter. I want the app to remember the login via Spring security's remember me functionality so that the user need to have to login frequently.

I have the parts that will call out to facebook and get the access_token that will identify the user. I can login the user using

```
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials, authorities));
```

I am trying to use similar approach to add remember me functionality by

```
    RememberMeAuthenticationToken auth = new RememberMeAuthenticationToken(key, principal, authorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

While this logs in the user, it does not set the remember me cookie. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to inject the implementation of `RememberMeServices` interface and then try to do:

```
rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);
```

Be sure that `_spring_security_remember_me` parameter is present in the request.

Comment: Does the request with the remember me parameter need to be a POST?

Comment: Also, do I need to write my own implementation of the remember me service?