# No Spring Security Remember me cookie created when logging in programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-social

Right after registration (sign up) I'm logging in my user programmatically via Spring Security:

```
public register(HttpServletRequest request, String user, String password) {
    ...
    request.login(user, password);
}
```

This works fine, but it doesn't create the remember-me cookie (although with interactive login the cookie is created fine).
Now I've read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806921/log-user-in-with-remember-me-functionality-in-spring-3-1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041685/set-spring-security-remember-me-cookie-after-login-via-facebook?rq=1) answer, that you have to wire in the implementation of `RememberMeServices` (I use `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`) and then call `onLoginSuccess`. I haven't been successful to autowire `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`.
How to make this work? Is this the right way? Why Spring Security doesn't offer a more convenient way?

P.S.: This is an excerpt from my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(new MyPersistentTokenRepository())
                .rememberMeCookieName("rememberme")
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24) 
                .alwaysRemember(true)
                .useSecureCookie(true)
                .and()
            ....
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't mention the Spring version. Below configuration will work with Spring 4 but you can modify it for other version. In your `WebSecConf` class autowire `PersistentTokenRepository` and `UserDetailsService` interfaces. Add Bean to get `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` instance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
PersistentTokenRepository persistenceTokenRepository;
@Autowired
UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistenceTokenRepository)
                .rememberMeCookieName("rememberme")
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24) 
                .alwaysRemember(true)
                .useSecureCookie(true)
                .and()
            ....
       ...
    }

@Bean
public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistenceTokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("rememberme", userDetailsService, persistenceTokenRepository);
    persistenceTokenBasedservice.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    return persistenceTokenBasedservice;
  }
}
```

Now in your Controller or class where you are doing programmatic login, autowire `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` and add below code inside the method to invoke `loginSuccess` method.

```
@Autowired
PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){
        persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think, this might be a good approach. The only problem is, that `persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` is not wired in - I get a `NullPointer-Exception` when calling `persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, auth)`

Comment: P.S.: I use Spring 4.

Comment: Once you define "@Bean" for PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices in your WebSecConf class as I posted it shouldn't be null when you autowire it in Controller.

Comment: OK - I understand now: it has to be autowired into a Spring-managed component - into an object, that  has been built by `new` it won't wire.

Comment: Is this solution PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices as global class attribute) thread safe? Or will there be undefined effects, when it will be used by multiple users?

Comment: It worked, thanks. Is it documented in Spring 4 docs? Or you just found out from code or so?

Comment: If you use a custom cookie name you have to call `persistenceTokenBasedservice.setCookieName("cookiename")` as the service will use "remember-me" by default.

Comment: @abaghel, can you take a look at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201688/implementing-spring-security-remember-me

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled on this issue and struggled a bit to get everything working correctly, for future reference this is how to set things up.

Define a `RememberMeService` bean configured to your needs.

Use `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` if you want a simple hash based token system or `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` if you'd rather persist the tokens to database. Both solutions are described in further details here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/remember-me.html

Please note that the constructor first argument is *not* the cookie name but the key used to validate remember-me tokens.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityBeans {
    @Autowire
    PersistentTokenRepository persistenceTokenRepository;
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistenceTokenBasedservice = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("remember-me-key", userDetailsService, persistenceTokenRepository);
        persistenceTokenBasedservice.setCookieName("rememberme");
        persistenceTokenBasedservice.setTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24);
        persistenceTokenBasedservice.setAlwaysRemember(true);
        persistenceTokenBasedservice.setUseSecureCookie(true);
        return persistenceTokenBasedservice;
    }
}
```

You should inject the `RememberMeService` directly when configuring `HttpSecurity`. You also have to configure the exact same key as defined in your `RememberMeService` because the configurer also sets up the `RememberMeAuthenticationProvider` which checks that the remember-me token key generated by `RememberMeService` is correct.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecConf extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
                .key("remember-me-key")
                .and()
            ....
       ...
    }
}
```

And finally you should invoke `RememberMeService`'s `loginSuccess` in your method doing the programmatic login [as described in abaghel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265601/3665580).