# Spring Security - Authentication by URL

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have sent to the user's email some letter with unique URL and need to authenticate him by this url after visiting. Now in system implemented the custom Authentication provider but it work only after submit from login form . I have read about Basic HTTP authentication, but don't understand how it implement for my issue.

Thanks! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to log-in a specific user, you can use the result presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900994/programmatically-login-in-a-user-using-spring-security).