# Spring Security login automatically after user creation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have successfully used spring security to login users. But the issue is, right now on my web page, when a new user is created, he/she has to again go back to sign in page to login which of course uses spring security. Is there a way to login the user automatically using Spring Security as soon as a new user is created?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically login in a user using spring security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900994/programmatically-login-in-a-user-using-spring-security)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never done it, but i think you should do what it is described in the [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html).

> Once the request has been authenticated, the Authentication will
>   usually be stored in a thread-local SecurityContext managed by the
>   SecurityContextHolder by the authentication mechanism which is being
>   used. **An explicit authentication can be achieved, without using one of
>   Spring Security's authentication mechanisms, by creating an
>   Authentication instance and using the code**:
>
> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(anAuthentication);
>
> Note that unless the Authentication has the authenticated property set to true, it will still be authenticated by any security interceptor (for method or web invocations) which encounters it.

Comment: Seems like promising solution, let me try it now

Comment: used the following code 

MyUserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService .loadUserByUsername(newUserDomain.getEmailId());
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
    newUserDomain.getPassword());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

Answer (score 5):

do this

```
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (userDetails, password2, userDetails.getAuthorities());
authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);
if(auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
}
```