# Login Authentication using Spring Security and Jersey Restful web Services

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, jersey

I'm a new bie in Jersey Restful web services and Spring Security.

I have created a mobile app in which the data is fetched from backend using Jersey restful web services and JAVA.
Now we are integrating a login page. For authentication we are going with Spring Security DB authentication. 
Didn't find a solution in google for login based on jersey and Spring Security

My rest URL will be like this:

```
http://localhost:6060/Myapp/REST/services/Login;userName=abcd;password=xxxx
```

I dont know how to handle this with Spring Security.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [servlet filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or a [spring mvc interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) for extracting the credentials out of the requests.

If the credentials are valid you can log in the user programmatically by [updating the authentication object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900994/programmatically-login-in-a-user-using-spring-security)

Comment: And do not forget that, Spring does not consider `GET` requests by default.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try this and will post the answer.